# geom_line is behaving strangely

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

i'm having an issue with a pretty simple visualization.

i'm just trying to do a simple time series plot of some very clean data, which looks like the following. (it is from the `Fatalities` dataset from the `AER` package.)

```
Fatalities %>%
  select(year, state, fatal_rate) %>% 
  filter(state %in% c('ca', 'az'))

 year state fatal_rate
8  1982    az    2.49914
9  1983    az    2.26738
10 1984    az    2.82878
11 1985    az    2.80201
12 1986    az    3.07106
13 1987    az    2.76728
14 1988    az    2.70565
22 1982    ca    1.86194
23 1983    ca    1.80672
24 1984    ca    1.94611
25 1985    ca    1.88128
26 1986    ca    1.94548
27 1987    ca    1.98966
28 1988    ca    1.90365
```

when i plot it i almost get what i want, which is one line plot for each state, but there is this problem of the lines for different states connecting to each other for some reason. it's always one state connecting to another state from the end of its time series at the beginning of the other state's time series. if i add more states it just looks messier, and the result is the same: lots of different colored lines connected to each other.

anyone know how i can get ggplot2 to stop doing this? and any idea why this is happening so i can avoid such issues in the future? thank you in advance for any advice.

```
Fatalities %>%
  select(year, state, fatal_rate) %>% 
  filter(state %in% c('ca', 'az')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(year, fatal_rate)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = state), group = 1) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image: hi]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just make `state` a grouper rather than have them as the same group as you are doing this. `ggplot` will then provide the behaviour you desire:

```
library(tidyverse)
data(Fatalities, package = "AER")

Fatalities %>%
  select(year, state, afatal) %>% 
  filter(state %in% c('ca', 'az')) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(year, afatal, group = state)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = state)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image: plot]

This way it knows that these are two separate time series.